# Redirect and remove www and add https

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

This rule seems to work fine, but when I go to https://www.example.com it doesn't remove the www.

However, if I go to http://www.example.com it works as expected.

Why is it not redirecting from https?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove WWW" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: This rule actually worked for me. Are you sure that both HTTP and HTTPS URLs bind to the same website? You may need to add this rule to the HTTPS site if they are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment above, your rule actually worked for me in the scenario that you described.  However, I do not think that it handles the case when a request is made to an insecure url that does not contain `www` in the hostname.  For example, `http://example.com/blah/` would not be redirected.  The following rule below handles that case as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Remove WWW and Ensure HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The rule checks for a hostname starting with `www` or an insecure request.  If either condition is met, the user is redirected.

Comment: So it looks like the certification authentication happens first before the redirect, so the www subdomain isn't included in the certificate. So I get the certificate warning before the redirect happens and it looks like there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: Interesting... The SSL certificates that I've used usually have the www subdomain included.

Comment: yeah normally that's the case, the problem was it was a multi-domain certificate, apparently that's not the situation with them.